# How to Load Functions In OpenGL ES 2?

Tags: android, c, opengl-es-2.0

I searched for a long time and couldn't find any websites that describe how to do this.

Is eglGetProcAddress the only function needed to do this?

I tried the following, but it didn't even compile:

```
GLuint GL_APICALL GL_APIENTRY(*glCreateShader)(GLenum) = (GLuint GL_APICALL GL_APIENTRY(*)(GLenum))eglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
```

I also tried this, but the same error occured:

```
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)eglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted above is correct, but the GLES/gl2.h file's function prototypes should be deleted, and the functions should be declared the second way I described above.